# switching between different inputs in a form based on @media width size

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form. I want to use input A in the form if @media (min-width: 768px), otherwise I want to use input B.

The reason I need to switch inputs is because [select.js is buggy in mobile views, however it is awesome on desktop views.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39089924/jquery-select2-tags-bugs-in-safari)

Using `xs-hidden and xs-visible` with bootstrap or using `display: block/none` does not work. The inputs are still in the source code and will still be submitted.

example:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 hidden-xs tag-lg">
   <%= f.input :tag_list, input_html: { class: 'tags', multiple: "multiple" }, collection: ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.all, value_method: :name, placeholder: '', label: "Tags (seperated by commas):" %>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 visible-xs-block tag-sm">
  <%= f.label :tag_list, 'Tags (seperated by commas):', class: 'label-tags'%>
  <%= f.autocomplete_field :tag_list, autocomplete_tag_name_photos_path, :"data-delimiter" => ', ', 'data-auto-focus' => true, :id_element => '#tag_element' %>
</div>

@media (min-width: 768px) {
.tag-lg {
 display: block;   
}
.tag-sm {
    display: none;
}
}

@media (min-width: 100px) and (max-width: 767px) {
.tag-lg {
 display: none;   
}
.tag-sm {
    display: block;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the browsers you're trying to use, you could use javascript's matchMedia() method to detect the viewport's width (IE11+) or you can use whatever javascript library you're using (jQuery) to disable the controls at certain page widths.  Disabled controls don't get posted to the server when a form is submitted.

As you've already discovered, this can't easily be done purely with CSS because the controls will still exist in the DOM even after hiding them.

Note: You probably don't want to outright remove the controls from the DOM because you may need to re-add them based on window resize, device rotation, etc.

Untested example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (( window ).width() > 767){
        $('.tag-sm select').prop( "disabled", true );
    } 
    else{
        $('.tag-lg select').prop( "disabled", true );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will show/hide the relevant HTML code. If you want to eliminate HTML code with pure CSS, that's not possible. CSS only helps styling your content, not removing it from the DOM.

```css
.tag-lg {
  display: none;   
}
.tag-sm {
  display: block;
}
@media (min-width: 100px) and (min-width: 768px) {
  .tag-lg {
     display: block;   
  }
  .tag-sm {
     display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 hidden-xs tag-lg">
  BIG TEXT
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 visible-xs-block tag-sm">
  Small text
</div>
```

You can use JQuery to find out the screen size `$( window ).width();` and remove the requested elements according to the value you get.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (( window ).width() > 767){
        $('.tag-sm').remove();
    } 
    else{
        $('.tag-lg').remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: this does not work because the inputs will be in the source code still and will be submitted with the form still.