# What do I use to target this input to disable it with jquery .attr("disabled", "disabled")

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

i have tested the code and it works on other inputs but for some reason this input won't work. The input uses the [rails-jquery-autocomplete gem](https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete) which uses [jquery autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

**rails code:**

```
<%= f.autocomplete_field :tag_list, autocomplete_tag_name_photos_path, :"data-delimiter" => ', ', 'data-auto-focus' => true, :id_element => '#tag_element' %>
```

**source code:**

```
<input data-delimiter=", " data-auto-focus="true" data-autocomplete="/photos/autocomplete_tag_name" data-id-element="#tag_element" type="text" name="photo[tag_list]" id="photo_tag_list" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
```

**script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.glyphicon-plus').on("click", function(){
    if($(window).width() > 768) {
      console.log
      $('???').attr("disabled", "disabled")
    }
  });
});
```

I have tried: #photo_tag_list, #tag_element, #photo.tag_list.ui-autocomplete-input, input#photo_tag_list.

Comment: You need to recheck your code, you have an error here ->  `console.log`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRy following code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.glyphicon-plus').on("click", function(){
    if($(window).width() > 768) {

      $('#photo_tag_list').attr('readonly', true);// IF JQUERY 1.9+   $('#inputId').prop('readonly', true);
    }
  });
});
```

**Reason:** Input type text doesn't suport disabled,  to make the input type text disabled we need to use readonly attribute.

Comment: this works, and i will accept it as the answer, although i guess the input remains in the DOM??  i am trying to use this along with this topic -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39234293/switching-between-different-inputs-in-a-form-based-on-media-width-size

Comment: Do you wanna delete element from the DOM?

Comment: if you see the other topic in the comment... i want to have two inputs and then switch between them based on $(window).width... yes, i want to be able to switch/delete the inputs based on $(window).width

Answer (score 0):

The HTML element has `ui-autocomplete-input` as a class. I think that js code is wrong, because the listener is attached for `glyphicon-plus` class.

I will hope help you!

Comment: the glyphicon is clicked, then the code in the middle is run.